# Create view with two foreign keys from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, create-table, create-view

I'm still  new when it comes to SQL and SQL Server so please bear with me for this question. I'm working on a project that is similar to the simple hypothetical situation I have created below. I have a two tables that I am trying to create a view from:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp (
Emp_ID int IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL,
Emp_Name VARCHAR(10) NULL,
Emp_Boss int NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Emp_ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_emp_boss FOREIGN KEY (Emp_Boss) REFERENCES Emp(Emp_ID));

CREATE TABLE Dept (
Dept_ID tinyint IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL,
Dept_Name VARCHAR(10) NULL,
Dept_Boss int NULL,
Dept_Emp int NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Dept_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_boss FOREIGN KEY (Dept_Boss) REFERENCES Emp(Emp_ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_emp FOREIGN KEY (Dept_Emp) REFERENCES Emp(Emp_ID));
INSERT INTO Emp (Emp_Name, Emp_Boss)
VALUES ('Marshal', 101), ('Lilly', 101), ('Robin', 101), ('Barney', 104), ('Ted', 104), ('Tracy', 104);
INSERT INTO Dept (Dept_Name, Dept_Boss, Dept_Emp)
VALUES ('Math',101,101), ('Math',101,102), ('Math',101,103), ('Physics',104,104),('Physics',104,105), ('Physics',104,106);
```

So far I have this Create Statement:

```
CREATE VIEW Tests AS
SELECT Dept_Name, Emp_Name AS Dept_Boss, Emp_Name 
FROM Dept, Emp 
WHERE Dept_Boss = Emp_ID AND 
Dept_Emp = Emp_ID;
```

But this statement only creates a view with two rows which are the two bosses.
And I want something like this:

```
Dept_Name | Dept_Emp | Dept_Boss
Math            | Marshal     | Marshal
Math            | Lilly           | Marshal
Math            | Tracy         | Marshal
Physics        | Barney      | Barney
Physics        | Robin        | Barney
Physics        | Ted           | Barney
```

Is there anyway to do this? I know why the CREATE VIEW I have written returns only two rows. It is because only those two rows meet both conditions in the WHERE Clause. I have tried to use OR instead of AND but that return too make rows and a doesn't actually match the boss with the emp. Any help I can get on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your query is asking for those employees who are their own boss, basically. e.g. Marshal/101 and Physics/104 are the only two records where your condition is satisifed.

Comment: I know this and that is why my question was how to change the query so it doesn't ask for those employees who are their own boss. Thank for the edits to the question by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to join your EMP table two times for different conditions

```
Alter VIEW Tests AS
SELECT Dept_Name, EMP1.Emp_Name, EMP2.Emp_Name AS Dept_Boss 
FROM Dept
JOIN EMP EMP1 on Dept_Emp = EMP1.Emp_ID 
JOIN EMP EMP2 on Dept_Boss = EMP2.Emp_ID
```

Comment: I can't believe I completely forgot I could use JOIN. Thank you for the answer! This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @user3694592 You were already doing an implied join. The trick is really that you join to the same table twice.